# Is it possible to call a page method using jquery in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2007, moss

We have a custom aspx page with codebehind class deployed in a DLL in GAC. I am trying to call a method in the codebehind using jquery to get the autocomplete behavior for a textbox. The method has the [WebMethod] attribute. The code works well in a test asp.net application but when deployed to the SharePoint server, I am getting a "httpexception - Directory C:\Inetpub\wwwroot...\catalogs\masterpage does not exist. Failed to start monitoring file changes" error. There is no scriptmanager tag in the page.

Answer (score 0):

In Your code behind add his attribute above Your function [WebMethod] and then You should be able to call it through Jquery

for more info look here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

add this under your asp.net form tag

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server"/>
```

in Your code behind file add this function

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string SayHi()
{
    return "Hi";
}
```

and add this in Your aspx file

```
    <script>
        function GetHi() {

            PageMethods.SayHi(onComplete);
        }

        function onComplete(result) {
            alert(result);
        }

        GetHi();
</script>
```

and try not to place your codebehind in yr GAC

Comment: "The method has the [WebMethod] attribute." from hia question.